# Android ViewFlipper back to first view

Tags: android, viewflipper

My viewFlipper contains 15 LinearLayout.
After it reaches, I have a button "Back to menu".

I've used

```
showNext()
```

all the way to the 15th LinearLayout.
And now I want it to go back to 1st LinearLayout.
Anyone have any idea? How to bring it back to 1st Linearlayout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Call `showNext()`. Or, call `setDisplayedChild(0)`.

Comment: what if i want to diplay every activity in between ??with slide in and slide out animation?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code.

```
private ViewFlipper vf;
private float lastX;


case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
float currentX = touchevent.getX();
    if (lastX < currentX) {
        vf.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);
        vf.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);
        vf.showNext();
        }
if (lastX > currentX) {
            vf.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_right);
            vf.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);
            vf.showPrevious();
            }
break;
}
```